# Export interface from C++ DLL

Tags: c++, dll, virtual

I know that it is allowed to export global functions, C-like structures and pure virtual interfaces throw DLL, if I want other compilers to be able to communicate with them.

Also I know that what was allocated at DLL side, have to be deallocated at DLL side. Usually people create deleters functions, like here:

```
class IA
{
public:
    virtual a() = 0;
};

DLL_EXPORT IA* GetA();
DLL_EXPORT void DeleteIA(IA* ia);
```

To achieve rule "delete where created". But as I understand, it is possible to avoid deleter if interface will have virtual destructor:

```
//dllheader.h
class IA
{
public: 
    virtual ~IA() {}
    virtual a() = 0;
};

DLL_EXPORT IA* GetA();

//executable main
int main()
{
    IA* p = GetA();
    p->a();
    delete(p);
}
```

So, at client side there was allocated just memory for pointer and when we call delete(p), it calls destructor (that was implemented in DLL, so, should correctly work) and then free memory of pointer.
Am I right? Can anyone clarify what happens there?

Comment: That is not an interface since it has implementation

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, so, it's unsafe? If I will change virtual ~IA() {} to virtual ~IA() = 0; everything should be well?

Comment: You can only reliably export classes from a DLL if the DLL and the host exe use the same dynamic runtime. Are you obeying that?

Comment: I'm trying to export interface from DLL, that would be used by clients with other dynamic runtime.

Comment: I'm not sure if exporting this will matter, because there's nothing to export. There are no data members, and the only implemented member function (the destructor) is inline (because anything defined in the class definition is implicitly marked `inline`). So I don't think there's anything for clients to import.

Comment: The wisdom about not deallocating memory that was allocated on the other side of a DLL boundary is true, because 1) the allocator and deleter might not be using the same C runtime, and 2) even if they have the same runtime, some OSes (Windows) (sometimes?) uses a different heap for each DLL and the EXE.

But really, you never want (1) to be true anyway, for a C++ interface. If (1) is true, you *really* want to `extern C`, because there are other subtle hazards due to lack of standardization of linking. (C linking isn't standardized, but it's "conventionalized", and in practice always works.)

Comment: I do not see the use of adding a deleter function when you have a destructor, except that the former is necessary if you're doing extern "C" and keeping your types opaque. An exported destructor will do the same thing ( -- that is, run on that same side of the DLL boundary --), as long as importing is not sidestepped by inlining. (As a rule of thumb, don't inline things across DLL boundaries unless you understand the hazards.)

Comment: Basically, either a) you know the compiler and linker is the same for your lib and all its clients, in which case all you have to worry about is the different heaps; or b) you don't, in which case your exported interface should entirely be `extern "C"`, so, yes, you'll want deleters.

If (a), though, simply avoid inlining -- especially of constructors and destructors.

Comment: The `virtual` question is unrelated to any of this -- the entire purpose of marking destructors `virtual` is to cause destructors of *derived* classed to invoke when deleting through a pointer to this base class. Nothing to do with the issue of DLL safety, AFAICT -- even if the derived class is defined outside of your DLL.